# Getting an error: "querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vxgqt.mongodb.net" when connecting to mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting the below error in the terminal:
***Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vxgqt.mongodb.net did not connect***
on running the index.js file
It was working fine till yesterday and today on running it is giving this error.
This is the code snippet:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.vxgqt.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

**NOTE: I have provided the correct username and password in the connection url**

Comment: i had the same issue here however i recommend changing the driver verion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary fix and that is working: Under connect your application in MongoDB Atlas I selected node version 2.2.12 or later instead of 3.6 or later(which I used earlier). By selecting this, the application is now working fine as before

Answer (score 1):

`querySrv ECONNREFUSED` means that the attempt to resolve the SRV record failed to connect to a name server.

This is a DNS problem.  Your application will need to be able to resolve the SRV record for `_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vxgqt.mongodb.net` in order to use the `mongodb+srv` connection string.

Comment: Yes, change the DNS to google DNS worked for me on my ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your internet connection and then go to mongodb Atlas and check whether your ip address is available in whitelist or not.
for testing purpose allow all ip's to access and then connect again.

Comment: I have IP address set as 0.0.0.0/0, so it should be accessible from any ip address right?
And, I have also tried adding my ip also, still giving same error

Comment: Yes, still giving same error.
I found a temporary fix and that is working: Under connect your application I selected node version 2.2.12 or later instead of 3.6 or later(which i used earlier). By selecting this, the application is now working fine as before

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your username and password inside URI of mongoDB, that mean u need to take value of **CONNECTION_URL** constant variable and change  to current username of your account on mongoDB and change  to current password of your account on mongoDB