Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vzygb.mongodb.net while connecting to mongodb
I've tried everything using chatgpt and configuring it again. Creating a new project and then creating a cluster and then doing all the process again.
But this error seems to be stuck there. what is the problem? is the problem from MongoDb atla, that I've not configured it properly or anything else?
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const errorController = require("./controllers/error");
const User = require("./models/user");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const shopRoutes = require("./routes/shop");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findById("66c82709c6db121f94dd0d57")
    .then((user) => {
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

app.use("/admin", adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://vishalaggarwal_:Vishalrockk1@cluster0.vzygb.mongodb.net/",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then((result) => {
    User.findOne().then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        const user = new User({
          name: "Max",
          email: "max@test.com",
          cart: {
            items: [],
          },
        });
        user.save();
      }
    });
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// Error// 
Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vzygb.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/callback_resolver:45:19)  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vzygb.mongodb.net'
}


querySrv EREFUSED is a DNS error.  There are already several QA on this site regarding that, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875026/error-querysrv-eservfail-mongodb-tcp-cluster0-abcd0-mongodb-net/68903530#68903530 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017449/getting-an-error-querysrv-econnrefused-mongodb-tcp-cluster0-vxgqt-mongodb-ne/67030029#67030029

It started working when I changed my DNS server port, I guess it was just a DNS error varies from different internet service provider.
